# IdentityServer 4 with Azure AD as external provider hosted in Kubernetes pod

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, kubernetes, identityserver4

I have created a custom Identity Service that mainly uses Identity Server 4 with Azure AD as an external provider. I have configured azure ad, having all the required ids & secrets and locally was able to authenticate any registered user in Azure.

The problem appears when we deployed that service into Kubernetes. [image: Reply Url Error]

I have added a public URL like https://myidentitydomain.com/signin-oidc. In a pod, we have a different domain of identity service than public one (be-identity-service), but it is how it works in Kubernetes. Not sure that its the issue connected to reply URL failure. But also my identity service has to be hosted in private network in Azure.

Really appreciate for any given advice.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the sign-in button to authenticate with IdentityServer, do look at the URL to see what **returnurl** was actually sent to it and add it to the client definition.

For example:

```
https://demo.identityserver.io/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fdiagnostics
```

Comment: Return URL is a bit different than Reply Url. The ReturnUrl will be the URL that I am gonna be redirected once authentication is successful. Here it is:https://demo.identityserver.io/diagnostics. Reply Url is the one that specified in Azure AD -> App registrations and usually ends with /signin-oidc.

Comment: On every given example once you authenticate using Azure Ad, you have to add 2 methods: Challenge & Callback. Callback redirects to returnUrl then. From my side, it doesn't authenticates and doesn't calls callback action :(

Comment: are your identity Server behind a proxy server? is HTTPS/TLS terminated in IdentityServer or in a separate proxy?

Comment: We planned to make it behind a proxy. And currently Https/TLS is on the ingress controller level. And also planned to use gateway to allow only specific URLs. I believe that is an issue, but whether it is possible to do so?

Comment: i just know adding a proxy is a bit tricky, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62713022/dotnet-core-identityserver4-reverse-proxy and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62695611/identityserver4-different-behavior-from-docker-compose-than-manual-run

Comment: I also saw another post about ForwardedHeaders, will try it out, thanks.